# Matplotlib as a web plug-in

Tags: python, web-services, matplotlib, plot

I have a Python code for a scientific research that solves complicated differential equations and produces a few GBs of data, but in the end produces a series of plots using `matplotlib`. And the goal is to provide the result to as many users as possible, who use multiple platforms.

So far I've been developing a `TkInter` frontend so that the program can be run locally for Windows, Linux, and Mac, but I found it quite difficult to make it work on every platform without a problem.

One cheap alternative would be making a simple CGI so that it provides users PNG files of the plots, but instead of that I want to build a web frontend so that the program runs on a server and users can run it and get the plots via a web interface. Is there any API of `matplotlib`, or a web server script for such a purpose?

I would like the web frontend to have some of the functionality of `matplotlib`, especially zooming in/out, panning, and using third-party plugins like `mpldatacursor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [MPLD3](https://mpld3.github.io/index.html); it brings Matplotlib to the browser through the popular d3.js javascript library.

[Here](https://mpld3.github.io/examples/scatter_tooltip.html)'s an example of a scatter plot with tooltips and zoom capability.

Comment: Thank you so much, Benjamin! It looks like what I want. I will try it as soon as possible and come back to report the result!

Comment: No problem, hope it works for what you want!